# Match the text in two lines using sed in linux

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed

I have a pattern as below

```
#error value for eg1
$text=1
```

I want to replace above pattern as

```
#error value for eg1
$text=0
```

How to achieve this using sed in linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do :

```
sed '/#error value for eg1/{h;n;s/$text=1/$text=0/}' file
```

and if you have user input like your comments seems to say :

```
input=$1 # first argument of the script

# double quotes mandatory here for the variable `$input` to be evaluated :
sed "/#error value for $input/{h;n;s/\$text=1/\$text=0/}" file
```

Comment: sed '/#error value for eg1/{h;n;s/$text=1/$text=0/}' file

In the above command,I thought of taking eg1, $text value and file name as user inputs. Can you please help me in acheiving this task

Comment: Sputnick I have used below script                                             
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter eg value"
read $eg
echo "Enter errorvalue"
read $errorvalue
sed -i "/#error value for $eg/{h;n;s/\$text=1/\$text=$errorvalue/}" error.txt

looks like it is not updating error value. It is giving output as
#error value for eg1
$text=


but i want o/p as below

#error value for eg1
$text=0


Please help me sputnick

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
sed -n '/^#error value for eg1$/{p;n;s/^\(\$text=\)1$/\10/};p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/^(#error value for eg1\n\$text=)0$/\11/;P;D' file
```

Read two lines and only change the second if both lines match.